# Help explaining concept of polynomial used in Binomial Theorem

Tags: polynomials, binomial-theorem

There is this question that asks to find the first 3 terms in the binomial expansion of $(x+\frac{1}{x^2})^6$. The question itself is easy, but someone asks me $x+\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not a polynomial by definition, but how come all textbooks use the word "find its binomial expansion"? How come in maths we use some defined terms wrongly?

How can I explain this?

The easiest escape is: as long as there are 2 terms, we consider it a binomial. I hope there are some better explanations than this.

Helps are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Expansion through the binomial theorem?

Comment: Could you clarify what term is used "wrongly"? Mathematicians rarely define things wrongly or ambiguously, it just happens that some people can get a little sloppy when they talk when the context or the actual English might not be as important if things are clear between the mathematicians talking. Also, note that the binomial theorem is also defined for negative powers, so it's not wrongly defined in that case, if thats what's worrying you. Also, being super super rigorous can be annoying sometimes, some people worry less about the language/riguournsness and more about the actual concepts...

Comment: Just as @Mike said, one view is to consider binomial expansion of $(a+b)^6$ (which *is* a binomial by the strict definition) and then substituting $a=x$ and $b=1/x$. In other words, you apply the binomial theorem to find the expansion and then apply the resulting equality to your expression; this is shortened for the sake of brevity into "binomial expansion".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "binomial" is much older than "polynomial". The first dates back (at least) to Fibonacci in 1202, the other to Viete in 1591 (ed: after Stevins introduced "multinomial" in 1585, before that "universal (sum)" was used). In general, a binomial is just a group, usually a sum, of two terms. Thus the binomial theorems allow the expansion of powers of such sums. Which was extensively used to approximate roots, even long before this method was systematized as Newton's method by Simpson some years after 1700.

---

**Sources**

- Florian Cajori (1919): A History of Mathematics https://archive.org/details/ahistorymathema03cajogoog, page 139 (154 in scanned pages)
- Florian Cajori (1928): A History of Mathematical Notations https://archive.org/details/historyofmathema031756mbp, page 154 (170, Stevins), 181 (197, Viete)

---

Note also that in biology, an name of a species with two parts is a "binomial" or "binominal", and a name with three parts a "trinomial" or "trinominal".